# cant remove NA's with logi and convert them as int data type

Tags: r, type-conversion, na

```
SpecialcharactersforOKstamp: logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Blank                   : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

i have the above data in the dataframe...i tried to convert them as characters using `as.character(x)` fn and i got the output below

```
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [9919] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [9948] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [9977] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

if i try `is.na(x)==0` i get the output as `character(0)`
can anyone tell me how to remove NA's to zero and convert logi to int data type easily

Comment: You can try with `is.na`, `df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `is.na`

```
df1$Blank[is.na(df1$Blank)] <- 0
```

Or

```
df1$Blank <- as.integer(!is.na(df1$Blank))
str(df1)
#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ V1   : int  1 2 3 4 5
#$ Blank: int  0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = 1:5, Blank = NA)
```

Comment: while trying 3rd one, i got all my rows as NA and i got 1 1 1 in all my rows as output for the 2nd solution u gave

Comment: @anonymous  Based on the reproducible example I showed, it is converting to 0.  You can check whether the `NA` in your data is real NA or a character "NA".  If it is the latter, you can convert to real NA and change it to 0, or `df1$Blank[df1$Blank=="NA"] <- 0`